# How to make background image not repeat itself

Tags: html, css, vue.js, background, background-image

Here's my code:

```css
div#bg {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 
  }
```

```html
<div  id="bg" v-bind:style="{ background: 'url(' + require('../assets/kafa.jpg') + ')' }">
```

So, what I want is just one image covering whole page, but whatever I do, it's just div covering the whole page with image repeating itself (probably because I only access div with properties and not the image itself). I tried with different image sizes, but the result in always the same.

[Here's how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT2sG.png)

Thanks.

EDIT1: I've also tried with min-height: 100% and min-width: 100%, but it's not working still.

Comment: use `background-image` instead of `background` in your inline css.

Comment: Yup, that's the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

In the component (replace `background` with `background-image`:

```
<div  id="bg" v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + require('./assets/2.jpg') + ')' }">
```

And in the CSS:

```
div#bg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was really getting on my nerves. Works perfectly now.